# Markov models: Proving that an occupation law is a stationary law

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am currently studying Markov models. I am presented with the following definition, theorem, and proof:

> **Definition 3.** If
>
> $$\pi^*_{ij} := \lim_{n \to \infty} m_{ij}(n)/n$$
>
> exists for all $i, j \in S$ and $\sum_{j \in S} \pi^*_{ij} \equiv 1$, then $\vec{\pi}^*_i = (\pi^*_{ij} : j \in S)$ is called an *occupation law*. In matrix form,
>
> $$\Pi^* = [\pi^*_{ij}] = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1} (\mathcal{I} + \mathcal{P} + \dots + \mathcal{P}^n). \tag{4}$$
>
> **Theorem 5.** An occupation law is a stationary law.
>
> **Proof.** We are assuming that the defining limits exist, so the right-hand side of (4) equals
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\mathcal{I}/n) + \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1}(\mathcal{P} + \dots + \mathcal{P}^n) = [0] + \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1}(\mathcal{I} + \dots + \mathcal{P}^{n - 1})\mathcal{P} = \Pi^* \mathcal{P},$$
>
> i.e., $\Pi^* = \Pi^* \mathcal{P}$. The rows of this matrix identity have the form (3), i.e., $\vec{\pi}^*$ is stationary.

The definition for the **stationary laws** is as follows:

> **Stationary laws**
>
> **Definition 2.** A *stationary law* is any non-negative solution $\vec{\pi}$ of the balance plus mass equations, i.e.,
>
> $$\vec{\pi} = \vec{\pi}\mathcal{P} \ \ \ \ \ \text{&} \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{j \in S} \pi_j = 1. \tag{3}$$
>
> Note that if $\vec{\pi}\mathcal{P} = \vec{\pi}$, then $\vec{\pi} \mathcal{P}^n = \vec{\pi}$ for all $n$. This follows by applying the first result iteratively.

And a related theorem and proof is as follows:

> **Definition 1.** If the limit
>
> $$\pi_{ij} = \lim_{n \to \infty} p^{(n)}_{ij}$$
>
> exists for all $i, j \in S$, and if
>
> $$\sum_{j \in S} \pi_{ij} = 1, \ \ \ (i \in S), \tag{1}$$
>
> then for each $i$ we say that the row vector $\vec{\pi}_i = (\pi_{ij} : j \in S)$ is a **limit law** (or limiting distribution).
>
> If $\vec{\pi}_i$ is a limit law, then $\vec{\pi}_i = \vec{\pi}_i \mathcal{P}$, i.e.,
>
> $$\pi_{ij} = \sum_{k \in S} \pi_{ik}, \ \ \ (i, j \in S) \tag{2}$$
>
> **Proof:** Define the square matrix $\Pi = [\pi_{ij}]$, which exists by assumption. Definition 1 can be restated as $\Pi = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{P}^n$. But $\mathcal{P}^n = \mathcal{P}^{n - 1}\mathcal{P}$, so
>
> $$\Pi = \lim_{n \to \infty} P^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{P}^{n - 1} \mathcal{P} = \Pi \mathcal{P}$$

I am having difficulty understanding this part of the first proof:

$$[0] + \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1}(\mathcal{I} + \dots + \mathcal{P}^{n - 1})\mathcal{P} = \Pi^* \mathcal{P}$$

Specifically, I do not understand how we get the result that the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1}(\mathcal{I} + \dots + \mathcal{P}^{n - 1})\mathcal{P}$$

results in

$$\Pi^* \mathcal{P}.$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not particularly tied to Markov chains. It is simply the following calculation that makes sense for matrices $A$ with complex entries: if $L:=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n A^k}{n}$ exists, then

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{I}{n} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n A^k}{n} = 0 + \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k}{n} \right ) A.$$

This follows by linearity of the limit operation (first step) and continuity of linear transformations (second step). Now that inner limit is again $L$, because $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k}{n-1} \frac{n-1}{n}$ and $\frac{n-1}{n} \to 1$. So $L=LA$. You could also have obtained $L=AL$, but that is not particularly useful in the Markov chain context, in which you want the rows of $L$ to be invariant under $p \mapsto pA$.